# Highlight car of each sexpr in source

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sexp

All the syntax highlighting suggestions I've managed to find so far are keyword driven. I'm reading data written in s-expressions that doesn't have keywords, but the car of each list is still somewhat significant.

How do I persuade Emacs to highlight the first element of each list, as if it was a keyword, when it's some unknown ahead of time symbol?

Even better if that can be done while still seeing `;` to `\n` as a comment.

Some more detail was requested on format. The head of a s-expr may be another s-sexpr, to arbitrary depth, where only the innermost one's car would be highlighted. There's no quote, quasiquote, ?, [] or {} involved.

Only paren, whitespace and everything else is a symbol. No dot (car . cdr) or "strings" in the format but don't mind how they display.

Comment: We need more information about the `car` . Can it be a sexp itself? Or does it have a special syntax, e.g., numbers or identifiers?

Comment: Sure, ((head sexpr) others) is valid and would ideally highlight head. It would be nice for '(a b c) to not highlight within the quote but doesn't matter hugely if it does. The baseline here is all in monochrome. Anything in printable ASCII might be present in the symbol, format is delimited on parens and whitespace.

Comment: Is the remaining syntax lisp-like? I.e., can there be strings `"..."`, is there an escape character `\ `, do `?` `:` `[]` `&` have special meaning?

Comment: Please update the question itself with all such supplementary specification of what you're requesting. Comments can be deleted at any time, and are not searchable - Q&A need to stand on their own. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own major-mode which inherites the syntax properties from `emacs-lisp-mode` and has its own `font-lock-defaults`.

The inheritance from `emacs-lisp-mode` adopts the syntactic highlighting of `emacs-lisp-mode`, i.e., the highlighting of strings and comments.

The `font-lock-keywords` given in the `font-lock-defaults` of the following Emacs lisp snippet highlight the first non-sexp expression in lists without differentiating between lists and quoted lists.

You can use `hicar-mode` with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `hicar-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> or define your own entry in the option `auto-mode-alist`.

```el
(defvar hicar-font-lock-keywords
  ;; Highlight cars with word and symbol syntax.
  ;; Some whitespace characters are also allowed
  ;; between the opening parenthesis and the car.
  ;; But, no line breaks because this would
  ;; require multiline keywords and we don't want
  ;; to go into those details here.
  '(("(\\s-*\\(\\(?:\\w\\|\\s_\\)+\\)" . 1)) 
  "Font lock keywords in `hicar-mode'.")

(define-derived-mode hicar-mode emacs-lisp-mode "hicar"
  "An Emacs lisp mode that highlights the car of lists."
  (setq font-lock-defaults '(hicar-font-lock-keywords)))
```